# Is there a way to access enclosing instance `ObservableObject` to call `objectWillChange.send()` from anywhere in a property wrapper

Tags: swift, combine, property-wrapper, property-wrapper-published, swift-property-wrapper

I'm trying to make a property wrapper similar to `Combine`'s `Published` one(for my project needs), but with ability to modify the wrapped property by sending a value to a publisher, stored in `projectedValue`, like this:

```swift
// in class
@PublishedMutable var foo = "foo"

$foo.send("bar")
// ...
```

Here's the code of the property wrapper:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct PublishedMutable<Value> {
    static subscript<T: ObservableObject>(
        _enclosingInstance instance: T,
        wrapped wrappedKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T, Value>,
        storage storageKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T, Self>
    ) -> Value {
        get {
            instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].storage
        }
        set {
            let publisher = instance.objectWillChange
            // This assumption is definitely not safe to make in
            // production code, but it's fine for this demo purpose:
            (publisher as? ObservableObjectPublisher)?.send()
            
            instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].storage = newValue
        }
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable,
                message: "@PublishedMutable can only be applied to classes"
    )
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { fatalError() }
        set { fatalError() }
    }
    
    private var storage: Value{
        get { publisher.value }
        set { publisher.send(newValue) }
    }
    typealias Publisher = CurrentValueSubject<Value, Never>

    var projectedValue: Publisher { self.publisher }

    private var publisher: Publisher
    init(initialValue: Value) {
        self.publisher = Publisher(initialValue)
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        self.init(initialValue: wrappedValue)
    }
}
```

And here's the playground code that I used to test its features:

```swift
class AmogusComic: ObservableObject {
    @PublishedMutable var currentPageContent = "S O S"
    
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    func connect() {
        $currentPageContent.sink { newPage in
            print(newPage)
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
        objectWillChange.sink { _ in
            print("Update")
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

let amogusComic = AmogusComic()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // connect publishers and print initial content. prints "S O S"
    amogusComic.connect()
    
    // change the value of current page via setting a property, the amogusComic class will reactively print "S U S" after
    amogusComic.currentPageContent = "S U S"
    
    // take a property publisher and send new value to publisher, the amogusComic class will reactively print "A M O G U S" after
    amogusComic.$currentPageContent.send("A M O G U S")
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Just modifying the value both by modifying a property directly and sending a value to publisher work perfectly.
But I also want to call `objectWillChange.send()` anytime the value changes
The problem is that it only gets called when modifying the wrapped property directly, which is not correct behavior.

The test code outputs this

```
S O S
Update
S U S
A M O G U S
```

when I think it should output this

```
S O S
Update
S U S
Update
A M O G U S
```

As you can see in code above, I used `_enclosingInstance` static subscript to get the `ObservableObject` and call `objectWillChange`, but it turns out that Swift calls that subscript only when modifying a property directly (`amogusComic.currentPageContent = "S U S"`)

Getting `Mirror(reflecting: self).superclassMirror` also doesn't work, `superclassMirror` always returns nil

Can I somehow get the `ObservableObject` outside of `_enclosingInstance` static subscript? So I could call `objectWillChange` also when sending a value to the publisher

Comment: By the way, this isn't quite how SwiftUI's `@Published`/`@ObservableObject` works. See https://forums.swift.org/t/how-is-the-published-property-wrapper-implemented/58223

Comment: @Jessy this adds ability to change the wrapped value by sending the new value to wrapper’s Publisher. Value wrapped by @ Published can only be modified via ‘=‘ expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. We don't have access to a static subscript equivalent of `projectedValue`. It's Apple's secret, how a `Published` subscribes to its parent object's `objectWillChange`, without the need for its getter or setter to be called first.

You can only recreate (and you have) `Published`'s `projectedValue` if [the class  you use it with is not an `ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published).

That said, there's no need to, if your intention is just to have a `send` method.

```swift
final class Object: ObservableObject {
  @Published var published = ""
}

let object = Object()
object.objectWillChange.sink { print("objectWillChange") }
object.$published.send("new value")
// "objectWillChange"
object.published // "new value"
```

```swift
public extension Published.Publisher {
  mutating func send(_ value: Value) {
    Just(value).assign(to: &self)
  }
}
```

Comment: What a nice solution. I will test the code when I get home, I can’t access my computer at the moment

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a lot. I didn't even know about `assign(to:)`. Approved